# HTML 'a' tag missing the 'href' attribute

Tags: c#, html

I would like to ask regarding automatic navigation through website powered by Angular using C# WebBrowser class. The point is to download a certain file from the site. I can navigate to the correct page quite OK (I managed to resolve the issue with an 'input' element without any 'form' that surrounds it, weird angular stuff...). The issue is with downloading the file.

Obviously, I don't want to display the 'Save To' dialog to user that pops up when I invoke click on the element. The thing is, body of the page in the WebBrowser instance looks in the incriminated place like this:

```
<a class="label clickable ng-star-inserted" draggable="true">
    <i class="ng-star-inserted ico ico-file ico-ft-pdf"></i>
    <div class="text ng-star-inserted">
        <h4>SRS Peer Review Checklist</h4>
        <p class="ng-star-inserted">Breanne - 01/04/2019 10:06 PM </p>
        <p><span class="state-name ng-star-inserted"></span></p>
    </div>
</a>
```

while in my FireFox browser, the HTML looks like this (notice the 'href' attribute is there):

[image]

Surprisingly, the WebBrowser loaded page is missing the 'href' attribute of the 'a' element. All the rest works just fine, so the WebBrowser can't be totally broken. Is there something I am missing? Possibly some Angular-friendly setting that will allow the dynamically built attributes to display properly? The rest of navigation is done more by invoking 'click' or 'submit' events on particular HtmlElement objects.

Comment: There is an event attached to the `<a>`. It probably does something on click.

Comment: Yeah, that is the 'Save To' dialog, which I don't want to display to user, though, so it's not a way which I would like to take...